# Fedora 15 won't remember wireless password

Tags: fedora, networking, password, wifi, gnome-keyring

I just installed Fedora 15 beta with Gnome 3. I've done all the updates.

The networking applet asks for the wireless password every time it connects. I found [this bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=683675), which says that the issue is fixed in gnome-keyring-2.91.92-1.fc15. I have version 3.0.1-1.fc15, so this shouldn't be an issue.

Is there any other reason why the keyring wouldn't store the password?

Comment: Zifre: Any feedback?

Answer (score 1):

Did you update {lib,}gnome-keyring-*.fc15  packages? If so, I am sure after restarting the host/Gnome session, this problem should go away.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a much more recent Fedora version (F20), and gnome-keyring version was not the culprit.

Here is how I solved it :

1. Right click on nm-applet.
2. Click on "edit connections".
3. Select the connection you're having issues with, then "edit".
4. Go to the "Wi-Fi Security" tab and enter the wifi password.
5. Save and exit.